# Extract array from list of json strings using Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in my data frame which contains list of JSONs but the type is of String. I need to run `explode` on this column, so first I need to convert this into a list. I couldn't find much references to this use case.

Sample data:

`columnName: "[{"name":"a","info":{"age":"1","grade":"b"},"other":7},{"random":"x"}, {...}]"`

The above is how the data looks like, the fields are not fixed (index 0 might have JSON with some fields while index 1 will have fields with some other fields). In the list there can be more nested JSONs or some extra fields. I am currently using this -

`"""explode(split(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(colName, '(\\\},)','}},'), '(\\\[|\\\])',''), "},")) as colName"""` where I am just replacing "}," with "}}," then removing "[]" and then calling split on "}," but this approach doesn't work since there are nested JSONs.

How can I extract the array from the string?

Comment: update the question with proper input JSON

Comment: It's proper, there are around 20 to 30 fields which are all nullable, I have tried showing that through a sample. Is there something specific you want to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
// Initial DataFrame

df.show(false)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|columnName                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"name":"a","info":{"age":"1","grade":"b"},"other":7},{"random":"x"}]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- columnName: string (nullable = true)
 
// toArray is a user defined function that parses an array of json objects which is present as a string
     
import org.json.JSONArray

val toArray = udf { (data: String) => {
    val jsonArray = new JSONArray(data)
    var arr: Array[String] = Array()
    val objects = (0 until jsonArray.length).map(x => jsonArray.getJSONObject(x))
    objects.foreach { elem =>
        arr :+= elem.toString
    }
    arr
}
}

// Using the udf and exploding the resultant array

val df1 = df.withColumn("columnName",explode(toArray(col("columnName"))))

df1.show(false)

+-----------------------------------------------------+
|columnName                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|{"other":7,"name":"a","info":{"grade":"b","age":"1"}}|
|{"random":"x"}                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------+

df1.printSchema()

root
 |-- columnName: string (nullable = true)
 
// Parsing the json string by obtaining the schema dynamically

val schema = spark.read.json(df1.select("columnName").rdd.map(x => x(0).toString)).schema
val df2 = df1.withColumn("columnName",from_json(col("columnName"),schema))

df2.show(false)

+---------------+
|columnName     |
+---------------+
|[[1, b], a, 7,]|
|[,,, x]        |
+---------------+

df2.printSchema()

root
 |-- columnName: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- grade: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- other: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- random: string (nullable = true)
 
// Extracting all the fields from the json

df2.select(col("columnName.*")).show(false)

+------+----+-----+------+
|info  |name|other|random|
+------+----+-----+------+
|[1, b]|a   |7    |null  |
|null  |null|null |x     |
+------+----+-----+------+
```

**Edit:**

You can try this way if you can use `get_json_object` function

```
// Get the list of columns dynamically

val columns = spark.read.json(df1.select("columnName").rdd.map(x => x(0).toString)).columns

// define an empty array of Column type and get_json_object function to extract the columns

var extract_columns: Array[Column] = Array()
    columns.foreach { column =>
    extract_columns :+= get_json_object(col("columnName"), "$." + column).as(column)
}

df1.select(extract_columns: _*).show(false)

+-----------------------+----+-----+------+
|info                   |name|other|random|
+-----------------------+----+-----+------+
|{"grade":"b","age":"1"}|a   |7    |null  |
|null                   |null|null |x     |
+-----------------------+----+-----+------+
```

Please note that `info` column is not of struct type. You may have to follow similar way to extract the columns of the nested json

Comment: I like the second approach but I am using an older version of Spark so can't "from_json", is it possible to achieve this with "get_json_object" ?. The first approach seems good as well but was looking for Spark library that I can reuse.

Comment: Second approach seems different to what I was looking for. The first one worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```html
val testString = """[{"name":"a","info":{"age":"1","grade":"b"},"other":7},{"random":"x"}]"""

val ds = Seq(testString).toDS()

spark.read.json(ds)
.select("info.age", "info.grade","name","other","random")
.show(10,false)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).